# Using INDEX MATCH to return multiple rows in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I'm currently trying to **use an INDEX/MATCH formula to return values from a data sheet into a summary sheet based on user entered criteria**.

This is the formula I have so far:

```
=INDEX(DATA!A:AF,MATCH(B1&C1&E1,DATA!AA:AA&DATA!AD:AD&DATA!AC:AC,0))
```

However **it only returns the first row that matches the results**. How can I get it to return all of the rows that match the results of the MATCH?

Thanks!

Answer (score 20):

Maybe consider the use of FILTER():

```
=FILTER(DATA!A:AF, B1&C1&E1=DATA!AA:AA&DATA!AD:AD&DATA!AC:AC)
```

Comment: This (and wrapping the result in `TRANSPOSE` to "switch" it from a column into a row) was exactly what I needed, thank you!

Answer (score 9):

For anyone else perusing this topic several years later, you can also use the query formula. This is a useful article to better help learn it:
https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/google-sheets-query-sql/

In this case, you can you use:

```
=Query(DATA!A:AF,"select * where AA = "&B1&" AND AD = "&C1&" AC = "&E1)`
```

The Query formula uses a version of the SQL to help you filter and return the exact data you need. I can't stress how useful it can be!

The string break and ampersands are necessary to reference a field outside of the data range notated in the first field of the Query formula.

Comment: QUERY can be really useful, but watch out for the trap that the references in the query don't update when in insert/delete columns or copy/paste the formula somewhere else.  You have to manually update the formula every time.  I actually found this comment while looking for a solution that would let me replace my QUERY with something else, and FILTER gave me what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

This formula

```regex
=FILTER(A1:C3,B1:B3="ADD")
```

On this table

| Alpha | Beta | Gamma |
| --- | --- | --- |
| MP | foo | 10 |
| PZ | ADD | 2 |
| CP | to | 5 |

Get this result

[image]

---

So great answer by @JPV to solve INDEX MATCH with FILTER formula.

Then related to the comment about TRANSPOSE makes rows and columns will be swapped, which it wasn’t required in my case